# Selenium not loading driver from specified path

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "driver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

However, if in debug mode I run `driver.service.path` the result is

```
/home/jd/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/118.0.5993.70/chromedriver'
```

My selenium version is 4.14. How can I properly setup the intended executable ?

Have tried some results that I found online, non helped

Answer (score 0):

I used ChromeDriver 118.0.5993.70, and it worked.
From here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json

"version": "118.0.5993.70",
"revision": "1192594",

```
"chromedriver": 
    "platform": "linux64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip"

    "platform": "mac-arm64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip"

    "platform": "mac-x64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip"

    "platform": "win32",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip"

    "platform": "win64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip"

"chrome-headless-shell":
    "platform": "linux64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/linux64/chrome-headless-shell-linux64.zip"

    "platform": "mac-arm64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/mac-arm64/chrome-headless-shell-mac-arm64.zip"

    "platform": "mac-x64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/mac-x64/chrome-headless-shell-mac-x64.zip"

    "platform": "win32",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win32/chrome-headless-shell-win32.zip"

    "platform": "win64",
    "url": "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win64/chrome-headless-shell-win64.zip"
```